# Regex match character before and after underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to write a regex with matches following:

- String should start with alphabets - [a-zA-Z]
- String can contain alphabets, spaces, numbers, `_` and `-` (underscore and hyphen)
- String should not end with `_` or `-` (underscore and hyphen)
- Underscore character should not have space before and after.

I came up with the following regex, but it doesn't seems to work

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\b_|_\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

**Test case:**

```
HelloWorld // Match
Hello_World //Match
Hello _World // doesn't match
Hello_ World // doesn't match
Hello _ World // doesn't match
Hello_World_1 // Match
He110_W0rld // Match
Hello - World // Match
Hello-World // Match
_HelloWorld // doesn't match
Hello_-_World // match
```

Comment: First step in such a case: build an array of test strings with desired ouputs. This both makes it clearer for other and lets you automatically test any regex.

Comment: "but it doesn't seems to work" can you also post the strings that give the wrong answer with your regex?

Comment: try `/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/`

Comment: This is unclear: the 4th condition makes no sense as the first 3 imply there can be no space in the string at all. I'd use `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$`, or, if 1 char input should be matched, `^(?!.*[_-]$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$`

Comment: "String should start with alpabets" First RE: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` ... you need to actually think about it more.

Comment: String can have spaces but not before and after underscore character

Comment: @DenysSéguret I've added test cases

Comment: Then rephrase the second condition: space is allowed too.

Comment: Also note the difference between an *alphabet* and and an alphabetic character.

Comment: From your examples, it seems digits are allowed as well. Please make this a consistent question.

Comment: @DenysSéguret, "Hello - World" here is string is not ending with underscore or hyphen, what is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*(?:[_-]$|_ | _))[a-zA-Z][\w -]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD1uV6/2)

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(?:[_-]$|_ | _))` - after some chars (`.*`) there must not appear (`(?!...)`) a `_` or `-` at the end of string (`[_-]$`), nor space+`_` or `_`+space
- `[a-zA-Z]` - the first char matched and consumed must be an ASCII letter
- `[\w -]*` - 0+ word (`\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) chars or space or `-`
- `$`  - end of string

Comment: I now see you were there one minute before me :-)

Comment: And as for matching an empty string, this little mod can be used (with an optional group around the consuming part of the pattern: [`^(?!.*(?:[_-]$|_ | _))(?:[a-zA-Z][\w -]*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/eD1uV6/4).

Comment: Satisfy all test cases. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use this one:

```
^(?!^[ _-]|.*[ _-]$|.* _|.*_ )[\w -]*$
```

[regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/rE0tS8/1)

For the test cases I used modifier `gm` to match each line individually.

If emtpy string should not be considered as acceptable, then change the final `*` to a `+`:

```
^(?!^[ _-]|.*[ _-]$|.* _|.*_ )[\w -]+$
```

#### Meaning of each part

- `^` and `$` match the beginning/ending of the input
- `(?!    )`: list of things that should *not* match:

  - `|`: logical OR
  - `^[ _-]`: starts with any of these three characters
  - `.*[ _-]$`: ends with any of these three characters
  - `.* _`: has space followed by underscore anywhere
  - `.*_`: has underscore followed by space anywhere
- `[\w -]`: any alphanumeric character or underscore (also matched by `\w`) or space or hyphen
- `*`: zero or more times
- `+`: one or more times

Comment: Similar to mine, but allows an empty string.

Comment: Indeed, that is a matter of interpretation. I added a `+` variant.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
^[a-zA-Z](\B_\B|[a-zA-Z0-9 -])*[a-zA-Z0-9 ]$
```

Broken down:

```
^               
[a-zA-Z]        allowed characters at beginning
(
 \B_\B          underscore with no word-boundary
|                 or
 [a-zA-Z0-9 -]  other allowed characters
)*
[a-zA-Z0-9 ]    allowed characters at end
$
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks, I got to know what I was missing. Cheers :)

Comment: There is a difference between *allowing* characters and *requiring* them. This regex *requires* a character at the start, and another character at the end, meaning it wont match single character input, like `A`.

Comment: @PalSingh: Just to make sure: what is the expected behavior for `Hello_-World` and `Z` input? And a minor one: what about an empty string?

Comment: Yes, _- is a case where is failing. How can I match it?

Comment: @PalSingh: See my answer and [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD1uV6/3).

Comment: yes, if `-_` needs to be matched then accept another answer. JavaScript doesn't have lookbehind, so this can't be fixed to match that. (`_-` could be solved with lookahead here)

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I love me some regex!

Would this work? `/^[a-z]$|^[a-z](?:_(?=[^ ]))?(?:[a-z\d -][^ ]_[^ ])*[a-z\d -]*[^_-]$/i`

I was a tad unsure of rule 4--do you mean underscores can have a space before *or* after *or* neither, but not before *and* after?

Comment: Underscores cannot have space before or after

Comment: Okay, I just want to be super-clear on what you need. There are 4 possibilities (ignore the quote characters, and question marks are for any non-space character): 1) "?\_?" 2) " \_?" 3) "?\_ " 4) " \_ "

Which of those are acceptable?

Comment: Okay. So my regex should work. Could you put the strings you're testing this against into the original post? (Or if they're really long and complex, just come up with some examples we can use to debug.)

Comment: Two issues: there seems to be a pipe missing in the middle, and this regex rejects single character input like `A`.

Comment: Okay, I've added support for a single character. I'm not sure what you mean by a pipe missing, though.